# Basic question about Bandpass and lowpass filter using Python

Tags: lowpass-filter, bandpass

I have a signal that is the sum of 3 signals that has just passed through a transmission channel. I need to put filters to this signal (bandpass and lowpass) and then apply demodulation and get one of the start signals.

I have these functions: bandpass and lowpass in Python, and I would like to know what values to assign to the parameters, I have the sampling frequency and the signal in question, but I don't understand what values to put to M (order) and fc (critical frequency). Are there recommended values for those? For example, the sampling frequency needs to be $F_s> 2F_{max}$.

The functions in question

```
def bandpass(signal,M,fss,fc):
    sos = signal.butter(M,fc,"bandpass",fs = fss,output="sos")
    b,a = signal.butter(M,fc,"bandpass",analog=True)
    w,h = signal.freqs(b,a)
    h = 20*np.log10(abs(h))
    filteredSignal = signal.sosfilt(sos,señal)
    return filteredSignal,w,h

def lowpass(signal,M,fss,fc):
    sos = signal.butter(M,fc,"low",fs = fss,output="sos")
    b,a = signal.butter(M,fc,"low",analog=True)
    w,h = signal.freqs(b,a)
    h = 20*np.log10(abs(h))
    filteredSignal2 = signal.sosfilt(sos,signal)
    return filteredSignal2,w,h
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked what butter -function documentation says about this all? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html

Comment: The order determines the rolloff rate of the filter and the critical frequency is the point where the magnitude response is -3dB. The higher the order, the sharper the edges of your filter will be, but the more processing power it will require. What you choose for these depends entirely on what requirements you have for the filters which you haven’t given us, so we can’t give you a good answer.